# Insufficient disk space in filegroup 'PRIMARY' - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, filegroup

Am getting following error:

> Msg 1101, Level 17, State 12, Line 1
>   Could not allocate a new page for database 'CTL' because of insufficient
>   disk space in filegroup 'PRIMARY'. Create the necessary space by dropping
>   objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or
>   setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

Properties of Database are as follows:

```
File Name               Autogrowth
CTL                     By 10 percent, unrestricted growth
CTL_Indexes             By 1 MB, unrestricted growth
```

And I got 60 GB of space remaining on the disk.

What would be the issue ?

Comment: Are both CTL and CTL_indexes placed on the same disk? Maybe you put it on different disks and there is no place on second disk?

Comment: Silly question: are those files in the PRIMARY file group, or another file group?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What edition of SQL server is this for? SQL Express has a 2GB limit on database size that is reported in this way.

Comment: It is SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Edition

Comment: +1 - I had the same error but was using SS 2005 Express. This helped me out a lot. Was not aware of a limit

Comment: For Sql express server 2008 and later the limit is now at 10 GB

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar error and solved it by changing file properties as under:

```
File Name               Autogrowth
CTL                     By 20 percent, unrestricted growth
CTL_Indexes             By 2 MB, unrestricted growth
```

Hope this works for you also.